# Deploying Liferay 6.1 Theme

Tags: liferay

I am very new to Liferay and still trying to understand deploying a theme. I'm more of a designer than developer at this point with knowledge mostly HTML/CSS for now, so working with SDK plugins has been a lil interesting needless to say.

But I (mac user) am currently registered as 6.1 EE user and using Liferay Developer Studio just trying to get a test theme deployed in my local instance to play around with. I have been following along the Liferay Documentation:

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-a-the-4

I am finding myself confused if this is still the proper steps for someone using Developer Studio compared to being a CE user using Eclipse Plug Ins.

Here is where I am at so far:
- Exported .war file from a Liferay Example Project (sample-styled-advanced-theme) after I just edited a few elements just for fun
- Dropped into /liferay-portal-6.1.10-ee-ga1/deploy
- confirmed theme is in tomcat-7.0.25/webapps/theme-name

When I go into my local portal and set up a new Site, I am not finding my Test Theme displaying for me to choose from. Is there something I'm missing here? I am unsure if I am still needing to use terminal for anything if Liferay Developer Studio can provide examples themes to work off of. Any clarification at all is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can see in log file `tomcat/logs/catalina.out` whether the theme is correct deployed.

Answer (score 4):

This link might help you, it has the steps and configuration - 
http://www.liferaysolution.com/2012/05/liferay-theme-creation.html

and as mark suggested keep your eyes on the log.

Answer (score 0):

Always check for the logs.. if it is saying that "xxx-theme is available for use", then only it will be available to be applied to a page.

Can you please attach the logs, that will help better to understand what error you are getting actually.